# Create a hot vector of specific columns with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe like this

```
   user_id    Amount    Event
1       28        22       e1
2       32        16       e2
3       28        55       e2
4       33        18       e3
5       28        28       e1
```

I am expecting output as

```
   user_id    e1     e2    e3
1       28    50     55     0
2       32     0     16     0
3       33     0      0    18
```

output explanation:

Instead of event name in a column, it should come into the column name with one hot vector style.
Instead of {0,1} in one hot vector, the amount (if present) should come.
If user has more than one entry for an event then sum of amount should come.

I tried to add `dataframe.get_dummies` method but it just gives me onehot vector representation but not the amount in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pivot table

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values='Amount',index='user_id',columns='Event',aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
```

Out:

```
   Event      e1       e2   e3
user_id         
28          50.0    55.0    0.0
32          0.0     16.0    0.0
33          0.0      0.0    18.0
```

Comment: Nice.  You can simplify a bit: `df.pivot_table(values='Amount', index='user_id', columns='Event', aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: @Naga it works Thanks. Just one question, In my question total 3 events are there e1,e2,e3 but i have a list of event [e1,e2,e3,e4]. e4 is not in the dataframe but still i want to include it externally with the hot vector with all the values of NaN. Instead of column can I use list of column names or something like that?

Comment: @you have to append the rows of event e4 in dataframe(df). if you have seperate dataframe of e4 information, concat both dataframes and feed to pd.concat function . It will work :-)

Comment: Yes concat option is always there. But still if I can use some predefined functions for that. Still thanks for the response. :)